# Optimization of solution for full page landscape figures

Tags: floats, landscape

Comments from various threads have been aggregated and considered resulting in the following implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\usepackage{pdflscape}%
\usepackage{varioref}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{capt-of}%

%
\newcommand\floatsummary{}%
\newcommand\floatdescription{}%

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

An introduction...

\section{Results}

Results are shown in Figure \vref{fig:example}


%
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\parbox[c][\textwidth][s]{\linewidth}{%
%
\renewcommand\floatsummary{Short float summary which will appear in toc}%
\renewcommand\floatdescription{Longer float description}%
%
\vfill%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
\begin{center}%
\fbox{%
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{example-image.jpg}\\%
}%
\end{center}%
\captionof{figure}[\floatsummary]{\floatsummary.  \floatdescription}%
\vfill%
}%
\label{fig:example}%
\end{landscape}%
}%

\end{document}
```

Key, desireable features are:

1. balanced positioning
2. maximizing use of page
3. rotating landscape pages in `.pdf`
4. avoid blank pages before or after figure
5. avoid blank pages when two or more consecutive landscape figures
   displayed

The inset mwe does result in a `.pdf` when one pushes compilation through a couple of errors.  The question is, what causes the `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` and how can the mwe be optimized / improved?

Comment: Removing the `\\ ` after `...{example-image.jpg}` helps.

Comment: Removing the `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` reveals at first glance that it may not do much.

Comment: Also, \centering inside an \fbox makes no sense as the \fbox is only wide enough to fit the contents.  In fact, all the fbox is doing is putting a \fboxsep (2pt) border around the image.  You can lose the \vfills if you use [c] instead of [s] in the \parbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version simplifies the code as much as possible.

I regard the purpose of `\newcommand` to be reserving global names.  For local definitions I use `\def`.

The purpose of adding `%` at the ends of lines is to prevent extra spaces.  It is only needed when lines end with braces, and not always then either.  For example, `\caption` begins and ends with a `\par` which absorbs extra spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{afterpage}%
\usepackage{pdflscape}%
\usepackage{varioref}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{capt-of}%

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

An introduction...

\section{Results}

Results are shown in Figure \vref{fig:example}
%
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\parbox[c][\textwidth][c]{\linewidth}{%
%
\def\floatsummary{Short float summary which will appear in toc}% local to environment
\def\floatdescription{Longer float description}%
%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
\captionof{figure}[\floatsummary]{\floatsummary.  \floatdescription}
\label{fig:example}% \@currentlabel etc. is local to \parbox
}% end of \parbox
\end{landscape}%
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion: now I have done another similar question with an old mwe.